# MySql data update and select synchronization problem in node js with multiple requests

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

Using expressJS I have an endpoint which is connected to a mysql DB where I am making a query and getting a set of data and assigning the first returned result to a user by updating a field to the user id.

The concept is that single row can **only** be assigned to a single user until the user has processed the row by hitting another endpoint.

Here is the query which gets the latest not processed rows:

```
const notProcessed = await knex('rows')
                .select('*'')
                .whereRaw(`status='Not-Processed' and (assignedTo=0 or assignedTo=${user.id})`)
                .orderByRaw('createdAt asc')
                .first();
```

and after I am updating the row to the user by doing:

```
await knex('rows').update({ assignedTo: user.id }).where({ id: notProcessed.id })
```

When multiple requests are sent to the endpoint **sometimes** I have the same row assigned to the more than 1 person.

Can't seem to find the reason or a solution for this. can anyone explain why this is happening and what is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple requests to node express mysql synchronization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062735/multiple-requests-to-node-express-mysql-synchronization-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Do both operations in a transaction and change the first query to `select for update`

```
const notProcessed = await knex('rows')
                .select('*'')
                .whereRaw(`status='Not-Processed' and (assignedTo=0 or assignedTo=${user.id})`)
                .orderByRaw('createdAt asc')
                .forUpdate()
                .first();
```

That way the row will be locked until the transaction ends.